# Creating list of unique_ptr using initialization list and make_unique fails in GCC 5.4

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, unique-ptr

I am using GCC 5.4 for compiling a test program in C++ 14.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int VALUE = 42;
    const auto list_ = {
        std::make_unique<int>(VALUE),
        std::make_unique<int>(0),
        std::make_unique<int>(0)
    };
}
```

GCC 5.4 fails with the below error message:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:13:5: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
     };
     ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/memory:81:0,
                 from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^
```

The same code compiles properly with Clang 3.5. See https://godbolt.org/z/PM776xGP4

The issue seems to be there until GCC 9.2 where it compiles properly.

Is this a known bug in GCC 9.1 and below? If yes, is there a way to solve this using the initializer list?

Comment: Possibly related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63149, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32515183/580083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
const std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<int>> list{
    std::make_unique< int >( 42 ),
    std::make_unique< int >( 0 ),
    std::make_unique< int >( 0 )
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Wz9jsKj7) (old gcc-5.4 tested).

Comment: I don't understand copy-elision properly, how does this work in this case? Also, why does this problem not arise when I try to compile using Clang?

Comment: It seems unrelated to copy-elision anyway.. Daniel Langr links seems more appropriate than my first explanation (even if the fix is correct).

Comment: Yeah, it seems some old bug in GCC. But your solution definitely works, thanks :-)